# How can I edit a file with copies in 2 different users in linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, user-management

I use AWS vps server and apache2 is installed in it. I want to edit a file "index.html" from 2 different accounts (i.e. 1st user "ubuntu" and second user "www-data"). By now, I try to edit the file but I got permission error so first I change (`chown`) permission to "ubuntu " and edit file and again change (`chown`) permission back to "www-data" otherwise I will get permission error in web browser.

I used `chmod 777 index.html` but this didn't help.

Please help me finding some good solution. Because this is tough to edit. I do have sudo permission if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. create a dedicated group and add the `ubuntu` and `www-data` users to this group. Then set with `chgrp` the group of the file and finally give the right permissions to the group with `chmod`.
2. If your server suports Access Control Lists (it should), you could use the `setfacl` command. You can read about the command [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) and [here](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists).